# Using each method to inject attribute with incrementing value

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I'm using jQuery to inject an attribute for delay animation into every list item. I want to increment 100ms into the delay of animation.

Here is my code

```
 $('.project-item').each(function(index){
    var delayNumber = index * 100;
    $(this).attr('data-aos-delay', 'delayNumber')
 })
```

I dont see the delay and I'm getting no console errors, any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: try  `$(this).attr('data-aos-delay', delayNumber)`, You dont need the `'` around `delayNumber`

Comment: James did it help?

Comment: Thank you ! worked

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).attr('data-aos-delay', 'delayNumber')` should be `$(this).attr('data-aos-delay', delayNumber)`

if you use `'delayNumber'` it would write "delayNumber" in the attribute, and not the value.

```js
 $('.project-item').each(function(index){
    var delayNumber = index * 100;
    $(this).attr('data-aos-delay', delayNumber).text(delayNumber)
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-item"></div>
<div class="project-item"></div>
<div class="project-item"></div>
<div class="project-item"></div>
<div class="project-item"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you use delay and queue of JQuery. Hope it helps!

```js
$('li').each(function(index){
    $(this).delay(index * 500).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("animated bounce");
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<ul>
  <li> Project Item </li>
  <li> Project Item </li>
  <li> Project Item </li>
  <li> Project Item </li>
  <li> Project Item </li>
</ul>
```